Why is this not running without a print in Python terminal, but running in Debug?
I am making a text adventure game in Python, using VS Code with GitHub. The menu script is as follows (at the moment).
def menuController(menuName:str, options:list):

    print(options)
    time.sleep(0.01)

    menuPosition = 0
    for i in range(len(options)):
        if menuPosition == i:
            options[i] = "*"+options[i]+"*   "
        else:
            options[i] = " "+options[i]+"    "
        print(options[i], end="")
    

menuController("ra", ["one", "two", "three", "four"])

When I run it, it outputs this:
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

It was missing a line at the end.
However, when I add a print("") after the menuController is called, it outputs this:
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
*one*    two     three     four

That last line is the one that I want visible in the final version
Why does it only output the second line when it has an empty print after?
Would this be fixable with some kind of output flush in the function definition?

print(options[i], end="", flush=True)

You probably should not modify options[i] in your loop. It should always be the core value of one/two/three/four and never the displayable text with surrounding asterisks or spaces.

This code works correctly for me in VSCode.

How do you execute the program? As in other comments, but written in a different way: probably there is some output buffering, so the output didn't make the final step (and possibly the cause is outside python (but there are way to make python flush buffers or not to buffer at all)

@matszwecja I have tried this, does not seem to help on its own.

it works as is inside IDLE ... maybee add a newline charcater / print("") at the end of  menuController function. maybe vsc is waiting a newline character to display the whole line

I have just been fiddling around for a few hours, and it now works?? I think that the comment telling me to use a print("") was probably the one that did it. Thank you! Also thanks for the advice to put options as a core value! That probably saved me a lot of time.
If anyone wants the code that I am now using:
import sys
from msvcrt import getch

light_green = "\033[0;92m"
reset = "\033[0m"

def menuNavigation():
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 13: #Enter
        return "Select"
    elif key == 224: #Special keys (arrows, f keys, ins, del, etc.)
        key = ord(getch())
    if key == 75: #Left arrow
        return "Left"
    if key == 77: #Right arrow
        return "Right"


def menuController(menuName:str, options:list):

    menuPosition = round(len(options)/2)-1
    navigate = ""
    optionsHOLD = options.copy()

    for i in range(len(options)):
        if menuPosition == i:
            options[i] = light_green+"*"+options[i]+"*   "+reset
        else:
            options[i] = " "+options[i]+"    "
        print(options[i], end="")
    print()

    while navigate != "Select":
        options = optionsHOLD.copy()
        navigate = menuNavigation()
        delete()

        if navigate == "Left":
            menuPosition -= 1
            navigate = ""
            if menuPosition == -1 :
                menuPosition = 0

        if navigate == "Right":
            menuPosition += 1
            navigate = ""
            if menuPosition == len(options):
                menuPosition -= 1

        if navigate == "Select":
            return menuPosition
        
        for i in range(len(options)):

            if menuPosition == i:
                options[i] = light_green+"*"+options[i]+"*   "+reset
            else:
                options[i] = " "+options[i]+"    "
            print(options[i], end="")
        print("")


def delete():
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    sys.stdout.write("\033[K")

If you want to change the colours:
colourBeingDisplayed = 0
colourDisplay = ["\033[0;31m","\033[0;32m","\033[0;33m","\033[0;34m","\033[0;35m","\033[0;36m","\033[0;37m","\033[0;30m","\033[0;91m","\033[0;92m","\033[0;93m","\033[0;94m","\033[0;95m","\033[0;96m","\033[0;90m","\033[0;97m","\033[0;46m","\033[0;45m","\033[0;47m","\033[0;44m","\033[0;43m","\033[0;42m","\033[0;41m","\033[0;40m","\033[2m",'\033[08m','\033[07m',"\x1b[90m","\033[3m","\033[1m","\033[9m","\033[4m"]
for item in colourDisplay:
    colourBeingDisplayed += 1
    print(item+"Colour "+str(colourBeingDisplayed)+reset)

And then just run it with:
chosen = menuController("Menu Name", ["Option 1", "two", "three", "four"])
print(chosen)

Thanks and Goodbye.
